# Adodb Commit and Rollback Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Following up my previous question. With much research I discovered that the method I insert data from Excel to SQL Server is most effective, code below.

What I really want advise on is how to set up the ADODB Commit and Rollback on this. I am not sure if it is possible, as my code inserts data into SQL Server via a FOR loop and I think Commit and Rollback needs to be done in one SQL execution?

**CODE**

```
Pre-loop code
            For i = 7 To LastRow

            'Check if it was sent - then skip iteration
                    With Worksheets("Admin")
                        If .Cells(i, 5).Value = "Y" Then
                            GoTo NextIteration
                        Else
                            Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([AA Number], [AA Name], [AA Role], [Project Name], [Series], [Paper No], [Task Name], [Amount], [Payment Justification], [Payment Identifier], [Date of Activity], [Half Day / Full Day], [Teacher Release (Y/N)], [Centre No], [Request Receipt Id], [Request Date], [Requested By], [Business Unit]) VALUES (" & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 2).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 3).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 4).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 5).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 6).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 7).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 8).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 9).Value & "'," & _
"'" & "Description: " & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 10).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"  //Project: " & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 5).Value & vbNewLine & _
"  //Series: " & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 6).Value & vbNewLine & _
"  //Paper No: " & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 7).Value & vbNewLine & _
" //Task Name: " & Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 8).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 12).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 13).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 14).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 15).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 16).Value, "'", ""), "*", ""), Chr(34), "") & "'," & _
"'" & .Cells(i, 22).Value & "'," & _
"'" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & "'," & _
"'" & Application.UserName & "'," & _
"'" & .Cells(i, 20).Value & "')"


                                'replace(replace(replace(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 10).Value,"'",""),"*",""),Chr(34),"")

                            Command.Execute

                            'Mark what was inserted with "Y"
                                .Cells(i, 5).Value = "Y"
                                Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 19).Value = 

"Y"
'''''' After loop code ''''
```

**EDIT**

My amended code is:

```
Private Sub insertAll()

    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim output As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

        Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=LO1WPFSASDB001;Initial Catalog=Londonmi01;User ID=SSRSuser;Password=ssrsuser1; Trusted_Connection=no"
        Conn.Open

        On Error GoTo CleanFail
        Conn.BeginTrans

        Dim sql As String
        sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([AA Number], [AA Name], [AA Role], [Project Name], [Series], [Paper No], [Task Name], [Amount], [Payment Justification], [Payment Identifier], [Date of Activity], [Half Day / Full Day], [Teacher Release (Y/N)], [Centre No], [Request Receipt Id], [Request Date], [Requested By], [Business Unit]) " & _
      "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

      Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project_Name")
        'if sheet "Project_Name" exists in ThisWorkbook at compile time, just refer to it by its CodeName;
        'define its (Name) property (F4) and use that identifier to refer to that sheet anywhere in code.
        'e.g. if (Name) is "ProjectSheet", then you can do 'ProjectSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value'.

        For i = 7 To LastRow
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("AA Number", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 2).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("aaname", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 3).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("aarole", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 4).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("projectname", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 5).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("series", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 6).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("paperno", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 7).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("taskname", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 8).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("amount", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 9).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("paymentjustification", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 10).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("paymentidentifier", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 12).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("dateofactivity", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 13).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("halfday/fullday", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 14).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("teacherrelease(y/n)", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 15).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("centreno", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 16).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("receiptid", adVarChar, Sheets("Admin").Cells(i, 22).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("requestdate", adVarChar, Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("requestedby", adVarChar, Application.UserName)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("businessunit", adVarChar, Sheets("Admin").Cells(i, 20).Value)

    cmd.Execute
Next
Conn.CommitTrans

CleanExit:
    Conn.Close
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Conn.RollbackTrans
    MsgBox "Something went wrong, transaction was rolled back."
    Debug.Print err.Number, err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

```
3708         Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up & open your connection:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "connection string"
conn.Open
```

Now begin the transaction, and setup error handling:

```
On Error GoTo CleanFail
conn.BeginTrans
```

Don't concatenate your values into the `sql` string. Set up `?` placeholders instead, and now you don't need to care for single quotes:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEP_Payments_Table] ([AA Number], [AA Name], [AA Role], [Project Name], [Series], [Paper No], [Task Name], [Amount], [Payment Justification], [Payment Identifier], [Date of Activity], [Half Day / Full Day], [Teacher Release (Y/N)], [Centre No], [Request Receipt Id], [Request Date], [Requested By], [Business Unit]) " & _
      "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

Now begin the loop. Set up your command, create and `Append` the parameters:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project_Name")
'if sheet "Project_Name" exists in ThisWorkbook at compile time, just refer to it by its CodeName;
'define its (Name) property (F4) and use that identifier to refer to that sheet anywhere in code.
'e.g. if (Name) is "ProjectSheet", then you can do 'ProjectSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value'.

For i = 7 To LastRow
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("aanumber", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 2).Value)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("aaname", adVarChar, sh.Cells(i, 3).Value)
    '...
```

Once all parameters have been appended in the same sequential order the placeholders appear in the command text / `sql`, proceed to execute the command:

```
    cmd.Execute
Next
```

Once the loop has completed, commit the transaction:

```
conn.CommitTrans
```

Now clean up and the "happy path" is done:

```
CleanExit:
    conn.Close
    Exit Sub
```

If anything went wrong though, this is where you need to handle it:

```
CleanFail:
    conn.RollbackTrans
    MsgBox "Something went wrong, transaction was rolled back."
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

This cleanup and error-handling code makes a number of assumptions about transaction and connection state; it's probably best to verify whether the connection is open before you try to close it, and whether there's a transaction to rollback. But you get the idea.

Comment: Great. Can you please explain to me how the '?' placeholder is set up and is connected to the parameter.append in the loop?

Comment: @OdaySalim if the SQL command string has 18 `?` placeholders, then you'll need to create and append 18 parameters to the command. They're *sequential/ordinal* parameters, so they need to be added in the same order they appear in the command string. The parameter's name doesn't really make a difference (they're *ordinal*, not *named* parameters), but naming it after the value it represents makes the code easier to follow & debug.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate to me with 2 of them and I will figure out the rest? Many thanks

Comment: @OdaySalim well you've got one right there, the second would be just more of the same.. edited.

Comment: Thanks - perhaps I did not articulate my question well. What I really mean is the create.parameter method name "aanumber" for instance, is that where it is supposed to go instead of a question mark? In other words: "VALUES ("aanumber","aaname", .... etc ...

Comment: no, the string needs to have the actual question marks, that's how ADODB knows there's a parameter that goes there.

Comment: Ah gotcha. This just looks bizarre to me.. I will try it now.

Comment: @OdaySalim FWIW you should always use parameterized commands. Concatenating the values into the SQL string not only makes the code hard to follow, it also makes the SQL vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327).

Comment: Thanks - I just tried it: getting an error. I will be posting code and error in question edit.

Comment: Please make a new question, this one is answered; make sure you have the correct number of placeholders and are adding the same number of parameters with the correct data type; a length argument may be required, pay attention to intellisense. "Chameleon questions" are discouraged on this site. Thanks!

Comment: that is, without a transaction, commit is executed by default?

Comment: @Alex78191 without a transaction, there's nothing to commit - operations are made "live", on-the-spot; that's fine for a single operation, but if you have multiple "steps" and everything must be rolled back if something goes wrong at any point, you'll want a transaction.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon is autocommit mode used by default? `All database statements are executed within the context of a physical transaction, even when we don’t explicitly declare transaction boundaries (BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK).

`

Comment: @Alex78191 yes.